# Javascript: sort multidimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimension array:

```
var somearray = new Array(
["110", "210", "310"] ,
["020", "120", "220"] ,
["020", "120", "200"] ,
["010", "120", "230"] ,
["130", "220", "310"] ,
["103", "113", "123"] ,
...
);
```

And I want to sort it with priority of first column, then second column then third column. How can I do that methodologically? Thanks!

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple:

```
somearray.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a[0]!=b[0]) return a[0]-b[0];
  if (a[1]!=b[1]) return a[1]-b[1];
  return a[2]-b[2];
});
```